# jquery history.go() to a specific page after navigating to different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a scenario where I want to return to a specific page after I navigate to different pages. The scenario is that a user makes a search, gets the results in the same page. He can then make updates on the a specific result on a different page. I would like to create a link that can bring the user back to the search result page. I am trying to user history.go(**specificnumber**), but how can I get the variable **specificnumber** from when the user make its first search to the number of page visited or loaded after the search. Or am I in the wrong direction for the implementation?

Comment: I think you probably just want to use standard hyperlinks here, and make your pages load their state from an object in local storage / cookie / session.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question but if you just want to go to a previous page you can use `window.history.back();`
Otherwise if you want to save all input data from user (to user) and use it to navigate next you can just use `document.cookies` or `localStorage`.